# How should I use INSERT INTO with a MS Access .mdb database?

Tags: sql, ms-access, vbscript

This is a work project but I'm having trouble getting my head around using "insert into" for an MS Access DB.

I've tried the following 3 scripts and all return different errors and of course I want my initial problem resolved but I would also appreciate knowing why they are all failing and what's different/best practice. These scripts are all modified ones I've found from searching around:

#### Script1:

```
Const adOpenStatic = 3
Const adLockOptimistic = 3

Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set objRecordSet = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

objConnection.Open _
    "Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; " & _
        "Data Source = C:\Users\itsupport\Documents\test.mdb"

objRecordSet.Open _
  "INSERT INTO Users" & _
  "(Id, Name, " & _
  "CertificateName, Password) " & _
    "VALUES ('michaelr', 'Michael Raymond', " & _
      "'NULL', '888')", _
        objConnection, adOpenStatic, _
        adLockOptimistic
```

#### Error 1:

Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement

#### Script 2:

```
Set objConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Dim rsData
strConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='C:\Users\itsupport\Documents\test.mdb'" 
objConn.Open strConnection
strInsertSQL = "INSERT INTO Users (iD,Name,CertificateName,Password) VALUES('" & _
                         michaelr & "','" & Michael Jenkins & "','" & - & "','" & 888 & "', objConnection, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic);"
Set rsData = objConn.Execute(strInsertSQL)
```

#### Error 2:

Expected end of statement

#### Script 3:

```
sql1="INSERT INTO Users  VALUES ('michaelr','Michael Jenkins',NULL,'888')"
constring="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;
  Data Source=C:\Users\itsupport\Documents\test.mdb;
    User Id=admin;Password=;" 
set con=createobject("adodb.connection")
con.open constring
con.execute sql1
con.close
```

#### Error 3:

Unterminated string constant

Comment: Script 1 and 3 look ok but it'd be helpful to confirm the column data types (are you trying to insert a string into a number or a value into an autonumber?). Script 2 definitely will not work because ` & Michael Jenkins & ` doesn't make sense (space in a variable name) and `'" & 888 & "'` doesn't close it's parentheses (should be `'" & 888 & "'"`) and you can see it's wrong because of how the syntax highlighting StackOverflow renders the colors.

Comment: also I don't see why you are doing `Const adOpenStatic = 3` and `Const adLockOptimistic = 3`. Values of the `ADODB.CursorTypeEnum` and `ADODB.LockTypeEnum` respectively, there is no need to define them again. Unless that is perhaps a clue that you do not have that library referenced...? Does this all compile? Compiling should be your first test for something being broken. It is the first item on the Debug menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Script1:**

1. Defining the ad* constants is necessary in plain VBScript (there are no libraries to be referenced)
2. Non-trivial concatenated strings should be assigned to a variable and displayed for visual inspection
3. `INSERT INTO Users(Id, Name, CertificateName, Password) VALUES ('michaelr', 'Michael Raymond', 'NULL', '888')` quotes NULL and uses the reserved word "Password" (see [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321266/en-us))

**Script 2:**

4. The concatenation 'works' if you double quote michaelr, Michael Jenkins, and - (whatever that means)
5. String concatenation in VBScript is a mess; unnecessary concatenation should be avoid (as in Script 3)

**Script 3:**

6. The syntax error is caused by the bad quoting and missing & _ in the definition of constring (you did it correctly in Script 1)

**In general:**

7. A lot of problems of building (and safely using) SQL statements simply vanish if you use parameterized queries
8. String concatenation in VBScript is a mess; using Arrays and Join, dedicated quote functions, and replacement of placeholders (no variable interpolation/expansion here) will result in better code